# Checkbox with a popup and description

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I need to have something when I check a box it will pop-up with a description and it will say click here to add it to ur "total". What I currently have is this:

http://pastebin.com/gy64A44q

Also the boxes after this first one doesn't come at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fancy this up with a jQuery dialog, but a `confirm` would do the trick:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var total = $('#total').text('0'); // cache DOM lookup and set innerText
    $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
        var self = $(this), // cache DOM lookup
            val = parseFloat(self.val(), 10), // grab value
            isChecked = self.is(':checked'), // grab state
            tot = parseFloat(total.text(), 10), // parse current total
            wasAddedToTotal = self.data('wasAddedTotal'),
            addToTotal = isChecked ? confirm('Add this to your total?') : false;
        if (addToTotal && isChecked && !isNaN(val)) {
            tot += val;
            self.data('wasAddedTotal', true);
        } else if (wasAddedToTotal) {
            tot -= val;
        }
        total.text(tot); // set innerText
    });
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mJA8c/

**UPDATE:**

For giggles, here's a demo somewhat fancied up using jQuery dialog: http://jsfiddle.net/mJA8c/1/

**UPDATE:**

The CSS problem is caused by jQuery adding a second `div` element when it appends the dialog (dunno why). The solution seems to be to append the dynamically created `div` element first, and then call `.dialog` on it:

```
$('<div />').appendTo('body').dialog({
    ...
});
```

as opposed to the original:

```
$('<div />').dialog({
    ...
}).appendTo('body');
```

This adds only the intended `div.ui-dialog`.

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mJA8c/2/

Comment: Pete, That's perfect! I just have a problem with the jquery css I get this line: http://puu.sh/55ABH.png the line is: <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block;"></div>

Comment: Can you post a link to the problem page, or post a jsFiddle reproducing the problem?

Comment: If you are unable to post a link or set up a fiddle, can you at least post the rest of the CSS in your question? Your original post does not specify any `div` elements with `class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content"` or `style="display: block;"` (which I might add is the default display for `div` elements, so it may be redundant...)

Comment: Sorry for late reply here it is: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js If I remove that line it won't show the pop-up

Comment: Correct, the pop-up is created using the `dialog` function which is defined in the jQueryUI library. If you remove the library, the dialog won't be defined and cannot be shown. What about the CSS problem you were having?

Comment: That's the css problem :p Or do I get it because I'm running it on a localhost? What I currently have: http://pastebin.com/DPqS5exN

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>checkbox</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function checkmy() {
     if (!document.form.agree.checked) {
        missinginfo = "You must agree";
        alert(missinginfo);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("Text information");
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="form" method="post" action="#" onSubmit="return checkmy();">
   <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" value="agree_terms" class="terms">
   <label for="agree">ready to shop</label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

You can style your alert box also:
Check out the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8cypx/12/

Comment: I don't need the sumbit button I need the pop-up when they select it if possible

Comment: then use **.change** event `$('#agree').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});`